# C# special characters

Tags: c#, special-characters

I need to verify that a string doesn't contain any special characters like #,%...™ etc. Basically it's a Name/surname (and some similar) strings, however, sticking to [a-zA-Z] wouldn't do as symbols like ščřž... are allowed.

At the moment I'd go with somewhat like

```
bool NonSpecial(string text){
    return !Regex.Match(Regex.Escape("!#@$%^&......")).Success;
}
```

but that just seems to be too complicated and clumsy.

Is there any simpler and/or more elegant way?

**Update:**
So after reading all the replies I decided to go with

```
private bool IsName( string text ) {
    return Regex.Match( text, @"^[\p{L}\p{Nd}'\.\- ]+$" ).Success && !Regex.Match( text, @"['\-\.]{2}" ).Success && !Regex.Match( text, "  " ).Success;
}
```

Basically the name can contain Letters, numbers, ', ., -, and spaces, any of the ",.-" must be separeted by at least 1 other allowed characters and there cannot be 2 spaces in a row.

Hope that's correct.

Comment: how come you don't use the `.Contains` method

Comment: Some other verification is more complex and i'd like the style to be consistent ( thus using Regex all the time )

Comment: It is already built into the framework. See Char.IsLetterOrDigit(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Unicode category for letters:

```
Regex.Match(text, @"\p{L}+");
```

See [Supported Unicode Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is my favorite answer. Many people are not aware that regular expressions can deal with Unicode and stick with old English-centric character ranges.

Comment: @Dougles As Joel pointed out, names do contain characters like "'", would Regex.Match(text,@"[^\p{L}'.-]") (if the regex finds a match, the text is not a valid name) be correct?

Comment: @pikausp It depends on the definition of "valid name". \p{L} matches everything IsLetter would, which does not include ', ., or - (refer to the [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/)).

Comment: @user2864740 I updated the question with current verification method, also note ^ in the regex.I'm searching for a character that is NOT allowed, thus there's not the +

Comment: @pikausp Ahh, I see. I would still use the affirmative case and *not* negate the entire regular expression result. (As it stands it's basically a double-negative.)

Comment: @user2864740 I thought + stands for one or more, which would return success for "Peter#", wouldnt it? As the regex would match Peter and it'd just ignore the #.

Comment: @pikausp But `\p{L}` doesn't match "#", so `^\p{L}+$` won't match "Peter#", but it will match "Peter". (Note the use of the anchors, such that the *entire* text must match.)

Comment: @user2864740 I know, but Regex.Match(text,"^\p{L}+).Success will return true, won't it? As there is a match for the regex in the provided string, which in this case, would be "Peter".

Comment: @pikausp Assuming the trailing $ anchor, it will match if the input is "Peter" but not "Peter#".

Comment: @user2864740 Ah, I totally missed that. Yeah I assume that would make more sense. Thank you

Comment: I agree that you'll need to handle more characters than just `\p{L}`. I think [Joel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25295628/1149773) says it best: You'll need to handle this on a best-effort approach, adding commonly-used non-letter characters without excessively diluting your validation.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `text.All(Char.IsLetter)`?

PS http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Thanks for the link ilya, I was actually surprised by some of those, especially the number 15.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is worse than you imagine.

There are literally thousands of allowable characters that can legitimately be part of a name, spread over hundreds of ranges in the various unicode alphabets.

There are also literally tens of thousands of characters that will never be part of a name. Think of all the emoji and ascii art characters. These are also spread over hundreds of separate ranges of unicode characters.

Sifting the wheat from the chaff via manual code, even regular expressions, just isn't going to work well.

Thankfully, this work has been done for you.  Look at the [`char.IsLetter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx) method.

You may also want to have an exception for the various allowed separator characters and accents that are not letters, but can be part of a name: hyphens, apostrophe's, and periods are legitimate, and all have more than one allowed unicode encoding. Unfortunately, I don't have a quick solution for you here. This may have to a best-effort approach, looking at just some of the more common.

Comment: How is `IsLetter` better (or, rather, different) than `\p{L}`? The documentation says "Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a Unicode letter", the remarks section appears to indicate it covers the same thing. I think it's unfair to consider a Unicode regular expression "chaff" if IsLetter offers no semantic benefit.

Comment: Period is actually allowed character in name?

Comment: @user2864740 Speed. If char is ASCII or Latin it doesn't need to bother with full Unicode and on big text it'll add up. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs#b8204f6ff0a505a2#references

Comment: @pikausp Yes, periods can be included in names. Remember, there are more cultures out there than just en-us, and some of them have some truly strange (to us) conventions for names.

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov Given the proposed task, I would really hate to see "speed" be used as the discriminator.

Comment: @user2864740 It's not just speed. Regex typically only correctly handles ascii characters.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn What about a *Unicode* regular expression with a *Unicode* character category: Why would it be "chaff" that "isn't going to work well" compared to IsLetter?

Comment: `\p{L}` matches "All letter characters. This includes the Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, and Lo characters" which, to my immediate reading, seems to be what IsLetter accepts (Uppercase, Lowercase, Titlecase, Modifier, Other).

Answer (score 0):

try using Linq/Lambda as well pretty straight forward

> will return true if it doesn't contain letters

```
bool result = text.Any(x => !char.IsLetter(x));
```